# Spectrum of integration operator on $C[0,1]$.

Tags: banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to find the spectrum of the operator $T: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ given by:

$$T(f)(t) = f(0) + \int_0 ^{t} f(s) ds$$

I can show that $0$ is contained in the approximate point spectrum with $f_n(t) = t^n$ and also that $1$ is in the point spectrum with eigenvector $f(t) = \exp(t)$.

I'm trying to show that in fact $\sigma_p(T) = \{1\}$. If we look at the subspace of differentiable functions then it's quite clear that the only eigenvalue is 1 (as the eigenfunction satisfies a differential equation) however I'm unsure how to extend this argument to the whole space?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Ok. Note that $Tf$ is always differentiable, thus if $Tf = \lambda f$ for some $\lambda \neq 0$, then $f$ is differentiable.